# How to make responsive MVP Swing GUI in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mvp, swingworker

I have an application that is built on passive MVP architecture using Swing in Java 7. My Presenter class does some time-consuming tasks and my View/GUI just calls the presenter's methods after an event. The presenter calls view's methods to update GUI.

Obviously, I don't want the long-running tasks to happen on EDT.

My first thought was to use a SwingWorker, but since it has only one doInBackground method, I think I would have to implement a SwingWorker for every single one method in Presenter.
Or would I?

Is there a simple way to make View/GUI run on EDT and everything else (i.e. Presenter's logic without it's calls to update View) on another (worker) thread?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your SwingWorker on the spot and wrap each presenter's code in that SwingWorker and call it, along the lines of a Command design pattern. The devil of course will be in the details, including the details of your code, information that we don't have right now.